# Download File automatically with browser that can be opened or read properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playframework

Frontend will send a post request to Scala Play Framework API to download a file. The response header is like :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8000
Content-Disposition:attachment; 
filename="logo_10248191299068944166699.png"; 
filename*=utf-8'logo_10248191299068944166699.png
Content-Length:53765
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 07 Sep 2017 13:05:57 GMT
Vary:Origin
```

My react js code is as below:

```
const FileDownload = require('react-file-download')
axios(req).then(response => (response.status === 200? response : 
null)).then(res =>
        {

        FileDownload(res.data, filename)

    })
```

It can be downloaded automatically but the file cannot be read. For example, if I download an image, the image cannot be rendered. If I download a zip file, it cannot be extracted. I already tried React-FileDownload, FileSaver, convert the res.data into arraybuffer with the creation of 8 bit array for loop - I.Just.Cant.Make.It.Work.

When I erase the extension format from ubuntu and open it on Atom, these shows up. And from the download tab in Chrome, it stated `blob:http://localhost:8000/4de5d808-67a6-4d4e-9920-24bd342664f6`

```
�PNG


IHDRwB���gAMA���asRGB��� 
cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q<bKGD�������   
pHYs.#.#x�?v�IDATx���w�e�Y����9WܹrN]]�-����0�2��,����t|
�=w�{ƹ�&����`LI��`0&I�J��j�����}��J���Pa�=W�~����ݭ��jϵ~�}��1`�|�;��֟zQj�?xz�����z�N-�^n5��$�m�:Uv��Sv�]�N��%=✾s����V��Ǜ?l����>$)��7��p�y{B]]�Ò�T��J:i�̥���+.�V5����$����u����u^�����-��%��tJ��ً�[��8��$}���UOI�{޻]v��N�3k׉�I�!�+$}�����I'���cW���_sNF�DҏI�Ip�9��$�`��
```

Comment: Searched through all the related problems found in stackoverflow, no one actually can solve it. Guess it is an impossible task to download file with React.... React is probably not that good yet =(

Comment: What is `filename*=utf-8'logo_10248191299068944166699.png`? Why do you need a charset for an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. It lies in the POST request.

```
url: url + '/storage/download_file',
method: 'POST',
responseType: 'blob',   //THE KEY TO SUCCESS
headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
```

Have to add `responseType: 'blob'`

I changed to FileSaver to download file.

```
var blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution above is working but I don't like to install excessive packages

**Axios**

```
url: '/url
responseType: 'blob'
```

**JS**

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.href = url;
link.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(link); // optional
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link); // optional
```